# How to use xargs to run command multiple times?

Tags: linux, xargs

I have a command that can be run once like:

```
heroku local:run python put_in_db.py --query='ffb557'
```

What I want to do is take a list of queries, like ["ffb557", "ttr887"] and run the command for each query. I tried running one to start, but get an error:

```
echo 'ffb557' | xargs heroku local:run python put_in_db.py --query='{}'

put_in_db.py: error: unrecognized arguments: ffb557
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you're missing an `-i` after xargs. `echo 'ffb557' | xargs -i heroku local:run python put_in_db.py --query='{}'` works for me.

Comment: Hmm I tried that but got: `xargs: illegal option -- i`

Comment: I guess you're on MacOS or similar. Try: `echo 'ffb557' | xargs -I{} heroku local:run python put_in_db.py --query='{}'`

Answer (score 2):

Linux:

```
% ( echo ffb557 ; echo ttr887 ) | xargs -i echo heroku local:run python put_in_db.py --query='{}'
heroku local:run python put_in_db.py --query=ffb557
heroku local:run python put_in_db.py --query=ttr887
```

Macos & BSD:

```
% ( echo ffb557 ; echo ttr887 ) | xargs -I % -n 1 echo heroku local:run python put_in_db.py --query='%'
heroku local:run python put_in_db.py --query=ffb557
heroku local:run python put_in_db.py --query=ttr887
```

Remove the echo to run the commands.